# useEffect not running on refresh

Tags: reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I'm having an issue with the useEffect hook on this blog site I'm building. Im trying to fetch all the blogs from the backend so I can use them to populate this section with the latest five blogs. When I use the code below, the empty array in the useEffect prevents the infinite amount of fetch calls, which is great.

But then I run into a problem where if I refresh the page or navigate back to it I get an error on line 35 saying "cannot find mainImage of undefined".

My question is how do I have the fetchCall populate the state and do so even on a refresh so that I can still access the info I need. Thanks!

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import CardItem from './CardItem';
import './Cards.css';

function Cards() {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchBlogs();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  },[]);

  const fetchBlogs = async () => {
    console.log('ok');
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/blogs');
    const data = await response.json();
    setBlogs(data);
  };


  return (
    <div className='cards'>
      <div className='header-container'>
        <img
          className='logo'
          alt='logo'
          src='https://Zi.imgur.com/MaLqLee.png'
        />
        <h1 className='cards-title'>Hot takes and hometown bias</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='cards-container'>
        <div className='cards-wrapper'>
          <ul className='cards-items'>
            <CardItem
              src={blogs.length > 0 ? blogs[0].mainImage : ''}
              text="Don't look now, but Zach Lavine officially kicks ass."
              label='Bulls'
              path='/bulls'
            />
            <CardItem
              src='https://i.imgur.com/EmVgHk2.jpg'
              text='The curious case of Mitch Trubisky apologists.'
              label='Bears'
              path='/bears'
            />
          </ul>
          <ul className='cards-items'>
            <CardItem
              src='https://i.imgur.com/ZZ5dLJU.jpg'
              text='How Did We Get Here? The Suddenly Bleak State of the Cubs.'
              label='Cubs'
              path='/cubs'
            />
            <CardItem
              src='https://i.imgur.com/MwgKmUM.jpg'
              text='Pace and Nagy: So, how much can we blame these guys?'
              label='Bears'
              path='/bears'
            />
            <CardItem
              src='https://i.imgur.com/Y2Eorvu.jpg'
              text='Thad Young: An Ode to the NBA Journeyman.'
              label='Bulls'
              path='/bulls'
            />
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Cards;
```

Comment: We need full code or at least some part of it but not as a screenshot

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fetch call is asynchronous. This means it is not guaranteed to be complete before the program enters the next line.

Because of this the `blogs` array will be empty at the first render. You can add an  check in the `src` CardItem component to only use the value returned from the `fetch` call when it is available:

```
<CardItem
  src={blogs.length > 0 ? blogs[0].mainImage : ''}
  ...
/>
```

An alternative would be to use the fact that `blogs` is an array and use the `map` operator to build one or more `CardItem`s.

```
<ul className='cards-items'>
  {blogs.map(blog => <CardItem
    src={blog.mainImage}
    ...
  />)}
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried both solutions and they both seem to result in the same problem I had to begin with. On their initial render, they work fine, but then when I refresh, blogs is undefined.

Comment: Actually I just deleted the [] in useState, and once I put them back in this seemed to work!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, and here is how I solved it..

First, I created a loading state, and set the initial state to true.

```
//  const [singlePackage, setPackage] = useState([]);

    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

then, in the `useEffect` hook, I set the state to false like so..

```
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
      setPackage(response.data);
    setLoading(false);
  })
}, []);
```

Then, I used a condition, if the loading state is true, return the spinner else return the component like so...

```
if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div  className="loadingContainer">
      <Loader
      type="ThreeDots"
      color="#00b22d"
      height={100}
      width={100}
       //3 secs
    />
    </div>
    )
  } else {

    return (
     // your code here
)}
```

I am using `react-loader-spinner`, and just styled the container
you can install it using...

```
npm install react-loader-spinner --save
```

the style for container ...

```
.loadingContainer{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,50%);
}
```